# What is the difference between subjunctive and indicative?

Tags: subjuntivo

I would like to seek your help in understanding this:

A los amigos de Julia les gusta que ella _____ mucho.

a) reírse
b) se ríe
c) se ría

I answered C (because it shows preference, like or dislike, and the main and subordinate clause have different subjects), but the book said it is B. I could not convince myself and so I asked several people and so far 1 answered B, 2 answered C.

From the looks of the answer in the screenshot below, both B and C are accepted, but what do you think?

[image]

Comment: If you could reference similar questions to this one, please feel free to add them here. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Both:

1. A los amigos de Julia les gusta que ella **ríe** mucho.

and

2. A los amigos de Julia les gusta que ella **ría** mucho.

are correct but slightly different.

In (1) it is a fact that Julia typically laughs a lot, and they like that. What they like is the laughter that characterizes her.

Instead, (2) means that Julia's friends like it when she laughs a lot. She may not be used to laughing a lot and only do it occasionally, but when she does, they like it.

The difference between the indicative in (1) and the subjunctive in (2) is then that the indicative refers to a fact, while the subjunctive only refers to a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

A los amigos de Julia les gusta que ella **se ría** mucho. **C**

A los amigos de Julia les gusta que **se ría** mucho.

**Presente de Subjuntivo 3ª persona (el/ella) "se ría".**

V. intransitivo **reír**, pronominal **reírse**

https://www.elconjugador.com/conjugacion/verbo/re%EDrse_pronominal.html

*Respecto a las diferencias entre el **indicativo** y el **subjuntivo**, en líneas generales, el modo indicativo se utiliza en español para transmitir hechos o informaciones, mientras que el modo subjuntivo se utiliza para hablar de ideas, de lo hipotético y lo irreal.*

> Regarding the differences between the "**indicativo**" and the
> "**subjuntivo**", in general terms, the indicative mood is used in
> Spanish to convey facts or information, while the subjunctive mood is
> used to talk about ideas, the hypothetical and the unreal.

El texto que indica tiene una redacción pésima y además unas cuantas faltas de ortografía, le recomiendo textos homologados u otras fuentes para iniciarse en el estudio del idioma español.

> The text that it indicates has a terrible wording and also a few
> misspellings, I recommend approved texts or other sources to start in
> the study of the Spanish language.